# Azure function app timeout for app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I did follow the guidelines mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout to increase the default timeout of function app host on app service plan from 30 mins to 2h by updating the host file with "functionTimeout": "02:00:00"

On checking function app's event viewer logs, I could see timeout limit is still 30m. Adding the error message for reference,

```
        <EventData>
            <Data>Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.6.27317.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException: Timeout value of 00:30:00 was exceeded by function: CreateRequestApplicationPostProcessor
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryHandleTimeoutAsync(Task invokeTask, CancellationToken shutdownToken, Boolean throwOnTimeout, CancellationToken timeoutToken, TimeSpan timeoutInterval, IFunctionInstance instance, Action onTimeout) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 631
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 547
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 503
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstance instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, IFunctionOutputDefinition outputDefinition, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 439
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstance instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 249
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstance instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 293
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 89
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass3_0.&lt;OnUnhandledExceptionAsync&gt;b__0() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs:line 54
   at System.Threading.Thread.ThreadMain_ThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
```

Appreciate your help in overriding a custom timeout value.

Comment: Have you enable the App Service Plan to `Always on`?

Comment: Thanks for checking @JoeyCai. Yes it is

Answer (score 5):

If you run on an App Service plan, you should enable the **Always on** setting so that your function app runs correctly.

Even with Always On enabled, the execution timeout for individual functions is controlled by the `functionTimeout` setting in the [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) project file.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Comment: I'm already running function app in an app service plan with always on and with the value "functionTimeout": "02:00:00" in host.json as mentioned in my initial question

Comment: Have you restart your function?

Comment: This did not solve it for me. The function is regularly restarted to pick up the changes above

Answer (score 5):

you can always use the attribute **[Timeout("1:00:00")]**  on function level to override the default timeout