# Azure function Stops after 10 min

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have azure function running on a app service plan.
The host file is this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "02:00:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {    
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 32
    },
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "02:00:00",
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 100
    }
  }
}
```

My code will runs for longer the 10 minutes but seems to stop after 10.
If i monitor the functions logging i can see that the job is started and 10 minutes later the service bus give a second deliveryCount. And the functions starts again.

The service bus settings for this queue are:

Lock duration : PT5M
Max size in megabytes : 5,120
Max message size in kilobytes : 256
Requires duplicate detection : false
Requires session : false
Default message time to live: P10675199DT2H48M5.477S
Dead lettering on message expiration : false
Duplicate detection history time window : PT10M
Max delivery count : 10

I am using Dot net functions.
The function is has a try catch so it will not throw an error and always finish.

I have tried to shorten the function timeout to 3 minutes, and than the log shows a timeout.
So i don't suspect the `functionTimeout` setting to be incorrect

Comment: @CSharpRocks my host.json is included in the question and the question says i am running on a app service plan,. so both suggestions in your link is not the answer

Comment: Check if this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/831683/timeout-in-function-app-hosted-in-app-service-plan) helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the default `FunctionTimeout` in App Service Function App is **60 minutes** but the `maximum Timeout` is unlimited as mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).

- Make sure you have turned on `Always ON` in `App Service=>Settings=> Configuration=> General Settings`:

[image]

If the issue still persists, consider using the Durable Functions async pattern which is best for longer processing times.

**My Observation:**

I have created a Function App with App Service Plan and deployed a service bus queue triggered function with `"FunctionTimeout":"01:00:00"`.

But, I got a warning in portal saying that `FunctionTimeout` should be between `"00:00:01" and "00:10:00"`.

[image]

Later, I changed `"FunctionTimeout":"00:10:00"` and it worked.

[image]

**References:**

[Azure function app timeout for app service plan - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586322/azure-function-app-timeout-for-app-service-plan)

Comment: You observation is not the same as my settings , you are running a Y1 plan : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1345601/what-is-function-app-pricing-y1-means Witch is a consumpstion based model we are runing a P2V2 plan. And we dont get the red notification.

Comment: Did you check if the other steps which I have provided help?

Comment: Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586322/azure-function-app-timeout-for-app-service-plan) answers regarding the same issue.